# Filter out the records of same policy numbers when it satisfies two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

By Using SQL server, I am trying to filter out the rows associated with a every policy numbers when the "Premium in Local Currency" is summed up to zero and then the last row has "Cancellation" in the "Current status" column.

---

```
 Workno#            MasterPolicyNumber  EffectiveDate  CurrentStatus    PremiumLocalCurrency 
16-05-01-035210-01  42-PRP-302562-01    2016-05-12          Bound        61438
16-05-01-035210-02  42-PRP-302562-01    2016-05-12        Cancellation  -61438
```

The following is the SQL query I use

```
    select 
               [Workno#],
               [MasterPolicyNumber],
               [EffectiveDate],
               [CurrentStatus],
               [PremiumLocalCurrency]
              from IT.dbo.View_Rater_Of_Record
        where [MasterPolicyNumber] = '42-PRP-302562-01'  
                order 
        by [Workno#]
```

But I want the result to be as zero records by filtering out the two rows since the sum adds up to zero and the last row has "Cancellation" as status. Thanks in Advance.

I also tried using Having clause, but I didn't get the results. The below line filters the second row since it is less than 1.

```
 Having SUM(CAST([Premium in Local Currency]as float))>1
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL server:

```
with Canc as
(
select MasterPolicyNumber, EffectiveDate, CurrentStatus, PremiumLocalCurrency,
       row_number() over(partition by MasterPolicyNumber order by Workno# desc) as Row_ord
from View_Rater_Of_Record
)
select C1.MasterPolicyNumber, sum(C2.PremiumLocalCurrency) as TotPLC
from Canc C1
inner join Canc C2
  on C1.MasterPolicyNumber = C2.MasterPolicyNumber
where C1.Row_Ord = 1
and C1.CurrentStatus = 'Cancellation'
group by C1.MasterPolicyNumber
having sum(C2.PremiumLocalCurrency) <> 0
```

EDIT: forgot the fundamental join...

Comment: This appproach didn't work.It gives the total instead of filtering out the rows

Comment: @user7394916 Yes, it gives you the totals of all the rows that did not end with a cancellation and did not total 0. It's a starting point that answers your question.

Comment: I wanted to filter out all the rows if there is cancellation in the "Current status" as well the premium adds up to 0

Comment: I tried your approach with little modification and it worked. Thanks